# How to display current navigation on "Body only" page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, navigation, page-layout

I create a new page and applied "Body only" page layout which is basically PageFromDocLayout.aspx

But it doesn't show current navigation. How do I show current navigation on left side of the page?
I have the code which will display current navigation but I don't know where to paste it inside page layout because there doesn't seem to be any space for that. Or is it something that I can enable disable from somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

By design the body only page layout omits the left navigation.

The easiest thing would be to use another page layout.

Comment: Ok please suggest me another page layout from the existing ones that will show current navigation.

Comment: Your best bet is to create a new page layout in SharePoint Designer: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=638